# ReactReduxContextValue while trying to access dispatch type error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, redux, react-context

i have an issue and i don´t know how to fix it. I am trying to use Redux with React-Typescript. And when i want to access the dispatch function of my store Typescript throws an Error. Below you can see the error and my code. The code works when i replace the type of the store to any. Do you have an suggestions how to fix this?

```
Argument of type 'ThunkAction<Promise<any>, IThemeState, null, IToggleTheme>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
  Property 'type' is missing in type 'ThunkAction<Promise<any>, IThemeState, null, IToggleTheme>' but required in type 'AnyAction'.ts(2345)
index.d.ts(19, 3): 'type' is declared here.
(property) payload: any
```

```js
const addName: React.SFC<{}> = () => {
      return (
        <ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
          {({ store }: ReactReduxContextValue) => (
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                store.dispatch(
                  toggleTheme({
                    payload: store.getState().themeState.darkMode,
                    type: EThemeActionTypes.TOGGLE
                  })
                )
              }}
            />
          )}
        </ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
      )
    }
```